# How to turn a string upside down

Tags: javascript, string, charat

Like `var name = prompt ("enter a name");`

```
For (var x =0; x<name.length; x++){
        var c = name.charAt(x);
        console.log(c);
}
```

If a name like kelvin is entered it will output

```
k
e
l
v
i
n
```

How to flip it like

```
n
i
v
l
e
k
```

Comment: looks like you got several decent answers, If they don't solve your problem, post a comment to clarify, otherwise select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you already did but by counting backwards like this:

```
For (var x = name.length - 1; x >= 0; x--){
        var c = name.charAt(x);
        console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the end and go back to the beginning.

```js
function flip(name){
  let len = name.length;
  
  // start at the end, and go backwards
  for (let i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  // another option is 
  // for (let i = len; i--;){
  
    console.log(name[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Name:
  <input id="nameInput" onChange="flip(nameInput.value)">
</label>
```

Comment: @kelvin andre, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes surely. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to turn the resulting string into an array calling  `split('')` then reversing it with `reverse()` and looping over with `forEach`

```
let name = prompt ("enter a name");

name.split('').reverse().forEach((el) => console.log(el))
```

Comment: this is too costly for just a simple function.

Comment: but it's more declarative and readable and early optimization doesn't make too much sense espcially in JS.